# Common House Spider got shrunked and appeared lifeless when touched by water

Tags: entomology, arachnology

I was trying to save a [house spider](https://www.nhm.ac.uk/take-part/identify-nature/spiders-in-your-home/house-spider.html) which was on my water tub, it was desperately trying to move out of the tub but due to the smooth surface couldnt manage, the tub was wet but not filled with water so I tried to assist it with a net, but it end up slipping into tiny puddle of water (like a drop or two) and it got shrunked (the water probably made its legs closed due to surface tension of the droplet)

I then managed to gently soak the water with paper towels but the spider appears lifeless.

Is it dead? The whole process of getting soaked in water and being dryed up with paper towels was less then a minute.

Now I saw some reference where it says that it takes [hours for spider to drown](https://www.interviewarea.com/faq/how-long-can-a-house-spider-survive-under-water). So is it likely that the lifeless spider on my paper towel is most probably still alive?

---

Update (1 hours passed) I notice some twitching of one of its legs, very subtle though. Not sure if it is still alive or just muscular spasm.

Update (2 hours passed) 3 of its legs seems to be oriented in a way that they are touching the base of paper towel. Maybe the twitching action was to fix its legs? The spider still appear lifeless though :(

Update (2 days later) no movement as the spider appears lifeless. Most likely died but I want to know why? how can a drop of water kill a spider, when ants and other insects survive. Is it the crushing force of water droplet tension that cramped its legs? I could see very subtle adjustments of its legs after I dried it. The final form it took is in the picture is below. Looks like it managed to re-orient its legs but in the process didnt survive.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Was the "wetness" in the tub hot, or in any way soapy?

Comment: your link shows a giant house spider - was it one of those, or a common house spider (a cobweb weaver)? If it was juvenile, like a recently hatchling or maybe past one molt phase, it can drown in a drop of water. Alternately, if the spider was old and near the end of its life, the trauma of getting pushed around and into water. It's hard to fully grasp in what way "it got shrunked". If it remains still, you can probably get a very clear picture to share

Comment: @JiminyCricket. the tub was cold, I am not sure about the soapy

Comment: @JimN the spider was common house spider about the size of a pea. But I dried it up quickly with paper towel. It seems lifeless in day 2 so I am certain its dead. Its quite delicate creature and I felt quite sad when it shrunked because of mere drop of water. Its still on my paper towel and I shall share picture once i am back.

Comment: @JimN eventhought it somehow managed to get all its legs on the paper towel to orient itself upright, it looks lifeless to me now :(

Comment: @JimN I have shared the picture.

Comment: @user0193 thanks for the update and photo. A spider that size should not drown that quickly upon contact with water. Where are you geographically located? This is not any 'house spider' I'm familiar with (not parasteatoda sp, not Eratigena sp like you linked). It is coloured like dysdera crocata, but I would need a look at its face/jaws to be sure. Not that its identification will lead to any answer on how it died, but for completeness' sake, a correct ID would improve the question quality.

Comment: @JimN, Ok I tried to open up its legs using cotton buds and since I am no expert it may appear botch job. I am currently in Dubai, does that narrow it down? I tried searching if the spider is in dormant state / hibernation because it did managed to fix the orientation of its legs rather slowly (over few hours) but under observation for 2days didnt come back to life.

Comment: Perhaps the reason it could not climb out of the tub was because it got soap residue on itself, and then when it fell into the drop of water that residue was able to cover the spider's body.

Comment: It seems like [Brown Recluse Spider[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_recluse_spider]], also that twitching was from changing cephalothorax pressure which they do to to extend their legs (she was alive at that moment) unlike other insects spiders have muscle only to flex their legs not to extend so in order to extend their legs they use their body pressure/ hydrostatic pressure for hydraulic legs they do this by changing heart rate. Also when they die they curl up for the same reason(heart stops hence no hydrostatic pressure to extend the legs)

Comment: @daemon looking at your link, it does appear that it was indeed Brown Recluse, so looks like it could be combination of factors that could have killed her, soapy water, drying action, lack of energy, potential damage during picking up with paper towels (even-though I was very careful and held paper towels from the further ends so as not to have any hand pressure applied). Also with your Iink realized that they are one of the species whose venom do require medical attention.

Comment: @DKNguyen so a soapy water can kill a spider if it is covered with it?

Comment: @user0193 Soapy water is used by exterminators on wasps. It coats them in a suffocating film.

Comment: This is not a brown recluse. The carapace is too shiny (like a Cicurina) and unmarked (unlike the brown recluse, which would have the notorious fiddle mark). Also, there are no brown recluses in that area. This looks like a Sahastata  https://inaturalist.org/observations/124127 (which does exist in that area).